# How to make iPad use the @2x.png high res images in "2x" mode

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I've read the documentation and googled until I couldn't google anymore, but still I cannot figure out how to make my iPhone app use the higher resolution images when displayed in "2x" mode on the iPad.

I have Icon.png Icon@2x.png and Icon-72.png and they work fine, but I don't want to have to rename all of my images. Also, the "2x" just seems to scale up pixels so text and IB objects look terrible. Is there a fix for this? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Note: This is *not* a universal app. I don't want to make it into a universal app. I just want it to scale up and look pretty on the ipad.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible, at least in Cocos2D apps. Matt Rix does exactly this in his app [Trainyard](http://www.trainyard.ca/) and it looks great on the iPad at 2x! He covers some of the details on his blog: [Retinafy your Game](http://struct.ca/2010/retinafy-your-game/).

Comment: Matt's using device detection to choose which graphics to display, which is an effective workaround. Not a fix, per se, but a good replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Apple want you to write native iPad apps, so they deliberately don't support this, and there's no way to make it happen that I'm aware of.

Comment: +1 for the likely motivation. From a developer's perspective if you're going to do all of the work to make a separate iPad app you ideally don't want your existing customers to not bother buying it because the existing iPhone app looks plenty good. I think this is especially true for games, where the iPad version tends to be a ton of work and a double-sized-using-@2x-graphics iPhone app looks almost as good. Note that similarly Apple doesn't draw text in native controls at the double resolution, despite the fact that it would have been fairly simple to implement.

Comment: @Matthew - Additionally, what happens when the iPad itself gets a Retina display?  I assume the base display of an iPhone application would then use the Retina display artwork, and the 2X would still need to be pixel-doubled.

Comment: Great point, definitely not future-proof. I do have some doubt that the iPad will get a Retina Display anytime soon, though: while it would be awesome and would be a nice feature-match for the iPhone 4, pushing 2048 x 1536 full-color graphics around, rendering OpenGL at a decent framerate, and generally looking good is a challenge for desktop PCs with big, memory-packed, heatsink-covered, noisy-fan-toting graphics cards. Packing that into an iPad would require truly astounding technology breakthroughs. I have no doubt that said breakthroughs will occur but not for at least 5-7 years.

Comment: @MatthewFrederick Stumbled across this comment and it made me smile, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

You can register for the notification `_UIClassicApplicationWillChangeZoomNotificationName` and scale your graphics appropriately, i.e. by setting the rasterizationScale on the CALayer to the value returned by `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`.